# Does assignment chages the entity's value

Tags: c++

Consider the simple assignment:

```
extern int a; //Declare a with the int type
a=4;
```

Is the value of the entity denoted by `a` just changed instead of recreation of the entity denoted by `a`?

Comment: There's no "recreation"; only declarations can declare variables, and `a=4;` is not a declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course. This is the whole point of assignment, you assign a value to something. An entity is created only if you define it by specifying the type, not by assignment. In this case, if `a` is not defined anywhere, then you get problem although.